# Check if the difference in time exceeds 30 min using moment JS/angularjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and we are using moment js for time manipulations.

Here is the scenario: I am getting last updated time stamp from back end (JSON) in unix time (like this 1485120726). My logic is to check if the last updated timestamp is less than 30 minutes. If so, cell should be in red color. This highlight will expire in 30 minutes (back to its original color block) unless there is a new revision.

I am stuck at this point to how to check the difference between current time stamp and last updated timestamp.

Here is my code:

```
  highlightFAA =(params):any=>{
  var CurrentDate = moment().unix();  //val 1485120726-currUnixtime
  var lastRevised= (params.node.data.lastRevised/1000); //Val 1484859960--backend is giving value in millisec so converting to sec

  console.log("currdate", CurrentDate);
  console.log("lastRevised", lastRevised);
  console.log("param node", params.node.data.lastRevised);

  //30 min is 1800 sec
  if(Math.abs(lastRevised- CurrentDate)>1800){
    return  {'background-color': 'black', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
  } else {
    return {'background-color': '#FFEB3B', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
  }

}
```

I am not sure if this logic is sufficient

I tried one other way to do it using `diff`

```
highlightFAA = (params):any => {

  var CurrentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  var lastRevised = moment.unix(params.data.lastRevised/1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

  console.log("currdate", CurrentDate);
  console.log("lastRevised", lastRevised);
  console.log("param node", params.node.data.lastRevised);

  var ms = moment(lastRevised).diff(moment(currdate));
}
```

But I am getting error saying `diff` cannot be used on string or number I am not sure how to proceed, I need some suggestions.

**here is the updated code I worked on which is giving difference in minutes.

```
 highlightFAA = (params):any=> {

     var CurrentDate = moment().tz("UTC").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
     var lastRevised = moment.unix(params.data.lastRevised/1000).tz("UTC").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
     var ms = moment(CurrentDate).diff(moment(lastRevised), 'minutes');

     if(ms>30) {
         return {'background-color': '#FFEB3B', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
     } else {
       return {'color': 'black', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
     }
 }
```

But here it is checking the time difference every time I reload a page, but what I need is to a way to recheck the time difference between currtime and last revised time dynamically and change color as soon as it exceeds 30 min time limit.

Comment: `but what I need is to a way to recheck the time difference between currtime and last revised time dynamically and change color as soon as it exceeds 30 min time limit`
you can use `$interval`

Comment: when i am using $timeout or interval i am getting error cannot find name timeout. even though i am injecting the service                                                      var __inject = [
  '$rootScope',
  '$compile',
  '$http',
  '$uibModal',
  '$timeout'
];                                                                                                 constructor(
    private $rootScope,
    private $compile,
    private $http,
    private $uibModal,
    private timeout;
  )

Comment: you are exceeding this question's scope. usually what you should do is create a new question instead. but I can easily see your problem, change `private timeout` to `private $timeout`

Answer (score 4):

Use `.subtract` to get the timestamp that was 30 minutes ago

```
let halfAnHourAgo = moment().subtract(30, 'minutes').toDate().getTime();
```

`.toDate` would convert the `moment` into a plain js `Date` object.

`.getTime` will return the date's timestamp.

Then check if your unix timestamp is bigger or smaller than what `moment` gave you

```
if (yourServerDate < halfAnHourAgo) {
    // color cell red
}
```

Comment: highlightFAA =(params):any=>{
  var CurrentDate = moment().tz("UTC").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  var faaLastRevisedDate = moment.unix(params.data.faaLastRevised/1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
  var ms = moment(CurrentDate).diff(moment(faaLastRevisedDate), 'minutes');
   console.log("ms", ms);
   if(ms>30) {
       return {'background-color': '#FFEB3B', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
   }
   else {
       return {'color': 'black', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold'};
  }
  }

Comment: @svarog- I was using above code to check for diff. But it doesn't provide a way to check it dynamically.